# ROC curve for different object detection methods in matlab

Tags: matlab, roc, haar-classifier, lbph-algorithm

There are varieties of object recognition  methods, which some of them are already developed in Matlab environment. I was wondering if there were a way that I can evaluate them using RoC curve. 
For instance, vision.CascadeObjectDetector in Matlab can be trained to use Haar, LBP,and HoG as features for training, I want to see each ones' RoC curves.